# InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document':The tag name provided ('/static/media/avatar.6043f57a.png') is not a valid name

Tags: reactjs

Hello Guys I am new to react and trying to clone Netflix through a youtube tutorial. So the issue here is that I am using an Image in a functional component, but it is not rendering properly

The error I am getting is this:

`InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/avatar.6043f57a.png') is not a valid name.`

My Functional Code

```
import './Header.css';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import HeaderOption from './HeaderOption';
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';
import SupervisorAccountIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SupervisorAccount';
import BusinessCenterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/BusinessCenter';
import ChatIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Chat';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import TabImg from './avatar.png';

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="header__left">
                <img src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/logo_9.svg" alt="Logo" />

                <div className="header__search">
                    <SearchIcon />
                    <input type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="header__right">
                <HeaderOption Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home" />
                <HeaderOption Icon={SupervisorAccountIcon} title="My Network"/>
                <HeaderOption Icon={BusinessCenterIcon} title="Jobs" />
                <HeaderOption Icon={ChatIcon} title="Messaging" />
                <HeaderOption Icon={NotificationsIcon} title="Notifications" />
                <HeaderOption Avatar={TabImg} title="me"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

My HeaderOption Code:

```
import './HeaderOption.css';

function HeaderOption({Avatar, Icon, title }) {
    return (
    <div className="headerOption">
        {Icon && <Icon className="headerOption__Icon" />}
        {Avatar && (<Avatar className="headerOption__Icon" src={Avatar} />)}
        <h3 className="headerOption__title">{title}</h3>
    </div>
    )
}

export default HeaderOption
```

Comment: What's your `HeaderOption` component code?

Comment: I'm Just adding it sir.

Comment: Added it sir...

Comment: It will come from ```Header.js``` Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <Avatar className="headerOption__Icon" src={Avatar} />)
> ```

You're doubling up on the `Avatar` symbol name, trying to use is as both a component name and `src` prop value. Within the `HeaderOption` functional component, `Avatar` only resolves to the prop value so it's like trying to use

```
</static/media/avatar.6043f57a.png src="/static/media/avatar.6043f57a.png" />
```

which obviously isn't valid markup.

Try importing the `Avatar` component using a different name. For example

```
// for a default export
import AvatarImg from "northern/air/temple"

// or for a named export
import { Avatar as AvatarImg } from "northern/air/temple"

// snip...

{Avatar && (<AvatarImg className="headerOption__Icon" src={Avatar} />)}
<!--          note the component name -->
```

Comment: Thank You so much, sir! Actually I'm 10 years old and I just tried a crash course of 11 hours and this error was coming.